# Would it be async if I call a number of async methods without awaits but then use Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm having a piece of code that I'm not quite sure if this would run asynchronously. Below I've made up some sample scripts which truly reflects the situation. Please note that the `GetAsync` methods are proper `asyn` methods having `async/await` keywords and return type using the `Task` of the related object.

```
public async Task<SomeResults> MyMethod() 
{
    var customers = _customerApi.GetAllAsync("some_url");
    var orders = _orderApi.GetAllAsync("some_url");
    var products = _productApi.GetAllAsync("some_url");
    await Task.WhenAll(customers, orders, products);
   // some more processing and returning the results
}
```

Question 1: Would the three above API calls run asynchronously even though there's no `await` before them? But, we have the `await` before `Task.WhenAll`?

Question 2: Would the above code run asynchronously if the `await` keyword is removed from before the `Task.WhenAll`?

I've tried to Google it around but couldn't find the proper answer to this specific situation. I've started reading [Parallel Programming in Microsoft .NET](https://www.amazon.co.uk/PARALLEL-PROGRAMMING-MICROSOFT-DECOMPOSITION-COOORDINATION/dp/9350042053) but yet have long way to finish it so I couldn't just wait it.

Comment: `await` awaits already asynchronous operations, it doesn't make them run asynchronously itself. The method as is isn't blocking. The answer is explained in all articles and tutorials about `async/await` - await awaits, it doesn't make anything asynchronous by itself. If you *remove* await, you won't be able to get the results from those tasks

Comment: `even though there's no await` ...await doesn't make a method async. Declaring the method `async` makes it async. `await` is a logical construct which tells the computer not to move to the next line of code until the awaited async method has finished, but at the same time allows the thread the code is running on to be freed up until the async code has finished. Therefore, if you want these jobs to run in parallel then you don't want to put `await` on them. But it _does_ make more sense to `await` then `WhenAll` method so your code pauses until all the jobs have completed.

Comment: P.S. if you want a more concise intro to async/await/tasks and what the advantages are, then read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: @ADyson *"Declaring the method async makes it async."* This is incorrect. What makes a method async is its return value. A method is asynchronous if it returns a `Task` or `Task<TResult>`, provided that this `Task` is not already completed at the moment it is handed back to the caller.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ok yes that's a good clarification, thanks.

Comment: @ADyson `async` doesn't make a method async. It just allows the method to use `await`. What matters is if it returns a task (or something else that is awaitable).

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1: Would the three above API calls run asynchronously even though there's no `await` before them? But, we have the `await` before `Task.WhenAll`?

1. If the methods are actually doing something asynchronously, then yes.

> Question 2: Would the above code run asynchronously if the `await` keyword is removed from before the `Task.WhenAll`?

2. If the methods are actually doing something asynchronously, then yes. However, it would be pointless to use `Task.WhenAll` without `await`.

Why I say "if": The [`async` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) doesn't magically make a method asynchronous, neither does the [`await` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await). The methods still have to actually do something asynchronously. They do that by returning an incomplete `Task`.

All `async` methods start out running synchronously, just like any other method. The magic happens at `await`. If `await` is given an incomplete `Task`, then *the method returns* its own incomplete `Task`, with the rest of the method signed up as a continuation of that `Task`. That happens all the way up the call stack as long as you're using `await` all the way up the call stack.

Once the `Task` completes, then the continuation runs (the rest of the methods after `await`).

But at the top of the call stack needs to be something that's actually asynchronous. If you have an `async` method that calls an `async` method that calls a synchronous method, then nothing will actually run asynchronously, even if you use `await`.

For example, this will run completely synchronously (i.e. the thread will block) because an *incomplete* `Task` is never returned anywhere:

```
async Task Method1() {
    await Method2();
}

async Task Method2() {
    await Method3();
}

Task Method3() {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

However, this will run asynchronously (i.e. during the delay, the thread is freed to do other work):

```
async Task Method1() {
    await Method2();
}

async Task Method2() {
    await Method3();
}

async Task Method3() {
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
```

The key is in [what `Task.Delay` returns](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5863). If you look at that source code, you can see it returns a `DelayPromise` (which inherits from `Task`), immediately (before the time is up). Since it's awaited, that triggers `Method3` to return an incomplete `Task`. Since `Method2` awaits that, it returns an incomplete `Task`, etc. all the way up the call stack.

Comment: ` this will run completely synchronously (i.e. the thread will block) because an _incomplete_ Task is never returned anywhere:` this was the best take away for me from you answer. Great explanation

Answer (score 2):

YES, to both questions with a lot of caveats.

await / async is just syntactical sugar that allows you to write async code in a synchronous way. It doesn't magically spin up threads to make things run in parallel. It just allows the currently executing thread to be freed up to do other chunks of work.
Think of the await keyword as a pair of scissors that snips the current chunk of work into two, meaning the current thread can go and do another chunk while waiting for the result.

In order to do these chunks of work, there needs to be some kind of [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8). WinForms and WPF both provide TaskSchedulers that allow a single thread to process chunks one by one, but you can also use the default scheduler (via `Task.Run()`) which will use the thread pool, meaning lots of threads will run lots of chunks at once.

Assuming you are using a single thread, you example code would run as follows:

`_customerApi.GetAllAsync()` would run until it either completes, or hits an `await`. At that point it would return to a Task to your calling function which gets stuffed into `customers`.

`_orderApi.GetAllAsync()` would then run in exactly the same way. A Task will be assigned to orders which may or may not be complete.

ditto `_productApi.GetAllAsync()`

then you thread hits `await Task.WhenAll(customers, orders, products);` this means it can go and do other things, so the TaskScheduler might give it some other chunks of work to do, such as continuing to do the next bit of `_customerApi.GetAllAsync()`.

Eventually all the chunks of work will be done, and your three tasks inside `customers`, `orders`, and `products` will be complete. At this point the scheduler knows that it can run the bit after WhenAll()

So you can see that in this case a SINGLE thread has run all the code, but not necessarily synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Whether your code runs asynchronously depends on your definition of asynchronous. If you look really close what happens, there will only be one thread that will do the stuff. However this thread won't be waiting idly as long as it has something to do.

A thing that really helped me to understand async-await was the cook-making-breakfast analogy in [this interview with Eric Lippert](https://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1). Search somewhere in the middle for async await.

Suppose a cook has to make breakfast. He starts boiling water for the tea. Instead of waiting idly for the water to cook, he inserts bread in the toaster. Not waiting idly again he starts boiling water for the eggs. As soon as the tea water boils he makes the tea and waits for the toast or the eggs.

Async-await is similar. Whenever your thread would have to wait for another process to finish, like a file to be written, a database query to return data, internet data to load, the thread won't be waiting idly for the other process to finish, but it will go up the call stack to see if any of the callers isn't awaiting and starts executing statements until it sees an await. Go up the call stack again and execute until the await. etc.

Because `GetAllAsync` is declared async, you can be certain that there is an await in it. In fact, your compiler will warn you if you declare a function async without an await in it.

Your thread will go into `_customerApi.GetAllAsync("some_url");` and executes statements until is sees an await. If the task that your thread is awaiting for isn't complete, the thread goes up the call stack (your procedure) and starts executing the next statement:`_orderApi.GetAllAsync("some_url")`. It executes statements until is sees an await. Your function gets control again and calls the next method.

This goes on until your procedure starts awaiting. In this case, the awaitable method `Task.WhenAll` (not to be confused with the non-awaitable `Task.WaitAll`).

Even now, the thread won't be waiting idly, it will go up the call stack and execute statements until is meets an await, goes up the call stack again, etc.

So note: no new threads won't be started. While your thread is busy executing statements of the first method call, no statements of the second call will be executed, and while statements of the second call are being executed, no statements of the first call will be executed, not even if the first await is ready.

This is similar to the one and only cook: while he is inserting bread in the toaster, he can't process the boiling water for the tea: only after the bread is inserted and he would start waiting idly for it to be toasted he can continue making tea.

The `await Task.WhenAll` is not different to other awaits, except that the task is completed when all tasks are completed. So as long as any of the tasks is not ready, your thread won't execute statements after the WhenAll. However: your thread won't be waiting idly, it will go up the call stack and start executing statements.

So although it seems that two pieces of code are executed at the same time, it is not. If you really want two pieces of code to run simultaneously you'll have to hire a new cook using `Task.Run( () => SliceTomatoes);

Hiring a new cook (starting a new thread) is only meaningful if the other task is not async and your thread has other meaningful things to do, like keeping the UI responsive. Normally your cook would Slice the Tomatoes himself. Let your caller decide whether he hires a new cook (=you) to make the breakfast and slice the tomatoes.

I oversimplified it a bit, by telling you that there is only one thread (cook) involved. In fact, it can be any thread that continues executing the statements after your await. You can see that in the debugger by examining the thread ID, quite often it will be a different thread that will continue. However this thread has the same context as your original thread, so for you it will be as if it is the same thread: no need for a mutex, no need for `IsInvokeRequired` for user interface threads. More information about this can be found in articles from Stephen Cleary